# Accessing the attributes of a has many association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model (user.rb):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bu_factors, dependent: :destroy
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
    before_save :downcase_email
    before_create :create_activation_digest
    ....
end
```

with a `has_many` relationship with the  bu_factor model which has a belongs_to relationship with the user model:

```
class BuFactor < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :asc)}
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :zero_till_one, :one_till_two, :two_till_three, :three_till_four, :four_till_five, :five_till_six, :six_till_seven, :seven_till_eight, :eight_till_nine, :nine_till_ten, :ten_till_eleven, :eleven_till_twelve, :twelve_till_thirteen, :thirteen_till_fourteen, :fourteen_till_fifteen, :fifteen_till_sixteen, :sixteen_till_seventeen, :seventeen_till_eightteen, :eightteen_till_nineteen, :nineteen_till_twenty, :twenty_till_twentyone, :twentyone_till_twentytwo, :twentytwo_till_twentythree, :twentythree_till_zero, presence: true, numericality: :true
end
```

in the users_controller I have an edit_settings action where I need to access the last created bu_factor belonging  to the current user, so that in the view I can display the single attributes with

```
<%= @bu_factors.zero_till_one %>
```

etc.

How can I achieve that? The controller action I have does not work:

```
 def edit_settings
    #should return the latest created bu_factors for the current user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @bu_factors = @user.bu_factors.order('created_at').last

  end
```

It returns a no method error for the `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy>`

Any help highly appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Comment: What error is returned exactly? What method does not exist? Please share the error message and the full stack trace.

Comment: It says that @bu_factors doesn't have a method "zero_till_one". Also the same when I create a Bu Factor instance in the console with a user_id, and access it from  an instance of the user, I get the same error.

Comment: When you debug `@bu_factors` what did you see there

Comment: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<BuFactor and so on>]>

Comment: @SebastianPeter You selected only one row which is last, you don't need to `order` after removing order then try and see what happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the user returned using `params[:id]` does not have any `bu_factors` related to it, because your relations are ok.

I think you need to try something like this in the controller:

```
if @user.bu_factors.count >= 1
   @bu_factors = @user.bu_factors.last
else
   @bu_factors = []
end
```

Or this is easier based on answers comment

```
@bu_factors = @user.bu_factors.last || []
```

And in the view:

```
<% if @bu_factors.present? %>
    <%= @bu_factors.zero_till_one %>
<% else %>
    <%= "You have none any Bu Factor" %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can replace the 5-line conditional statement in the controller with `@bu_factors = @user.bu_factors.last || []`.

Comment: @moveson Yes exactly, this is more easy to understand